# An error occurred when submitting an edit

Tags: support, edits, error-message

I had posted an answer on Stack Overflow which went through fine. I then decided it would be nice to add a couple of screen shots; but when I edited the answer, I got the "error occurred submitting the answer" message. I have no idea what it was about my updated answer that triggered this.

Can anyone explain what might have caused the rejection? It seems that the changes are very benign. I am puzzled, and hope for some enlightenment.

Comment: Stack Overflow was in read only mode for a short time, please try again now.

Comment: It's an edge case, you started to edit when the site was fine and submitted when it had some internal issues... don't think it's possible to catch each and every error and show the friendly message. Anyway, leave this around so we can refer others with similar problem in the future. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell (didn't have chance to try) when you browse to question while in read only mode, all edit links will be either disabled or gone, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow was in **read-only** mode when you tried to submit the edit.