# An error occurred submitting the answer on Editing answer

Tags: support, error-message

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993906/stopping-location-updates-after-an-outgoing-call-is-done-in-android) and tried to edit that as per OP's comment on my answer.

But when I click on 'Save Edits' after editing, I get an error saying `An error occurred submitting the answer`

Snapshot:

[image]

I already searched. I got [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214408/208463) answer which says that SO must be in read only mode. But I could edit [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520489/prevention-of-phone-number-detection-is-not-working-on-htc-device) without any issue. Why am I getting this problem?

Comment: This usually happens to me when I'm on an intermittent internet connection

Comment: @RichardTingle But I could edit other post, and after editing that post tried to edit that answer again, but same error. So may be Internet connection is not an issue.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried to edit that post and it was successful, what exactly did you try to edit in. Was it <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />  and was it code formatted?

Comment: Yes, noticed that you edited for testing. Yes, I tried to add that in code, and it was well formatted. @RichardTingle

Comment: Strange, I know code not formatted as code can upset it but the code formatting is supposed to prevent this

Comment: Finally I could edit that post. But question still remains, *why was I not able to edit that previously?*

Comment: @RichardTingle In unformatted code's case, it shows error saying that there is unformatted code (as far as I remember. It had happened a year ago, so can't recall.)

Comment: I think there are two kinds of unformatted code problems; one where it identifies it, doesn't like it and tells you. And annother where it doesn't identify it, thinks it's its own code and chews it up leading to assorted problems

Comment: Hmm. May be. I think only developers can tell the precise issue.

Comment: Probably true, but as the problem has resolved itself it may be difficult for them to identify

Comment: Maybe it was temporary glitch, maybe you have some rough user script...

Comment: May be. I had faced same issue before 3 days, but ignored it and continued with other work. As this happened second time today, I thought to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like edit wars. You've been submitting an edit to your first (old) revision, while the current revision (edited by another user) was already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20994272/2).

Comment: No. Because Richard edited that post for testing after I posted this question.